# Iterative Running Sum in SQL

Tags: sql, iteration, teradata, cumulative-sum, teradatasql

I want to create a running sum in sql that starts over each time it surpasses the value of 90. I have a list of dates, and once 90 days have passed since the original date I want it to start over at 0 again, iteratively. Below is my current code that outputs the second column given the dates provided, but my desired output is the third column.

Any suggestions on how to transform the code to give me the desired output would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT Dt
    ,r.Dt - Min(r.Dt) Over (ORDER BY Dt) AS current_output
FROM date_table
```

| Dt | Current Output | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/3/2019 | 0 | 0 |
| 4/10/2019 | 7 | 7 |
| 4/17/2019 | 14 | 14 |
| 4/24/2019 | 21 | 21 |
| 5/1/2019 | 28 | 28 |
| 5/8/2019 | 35 | 35 |
| 5/15/2019 | 42 | 42 |
| 5/22/2019 | 49 | 49 |
| 5/29/2019 | 56 | 56 |
| 6/5/2019 | 63 | 63 |
| 7/3/2019 | 91 | 0 |
| 7/17/2019 | 105 | 14 |
| 7/24/2019 | 112 | 21 |
| 7/31/2019 | 119 | 28 |
| 8/7/2019 | 126 | 35 |
| 8/14/2019 | 133 | 42 |
| 8/21/2019 | 140 | 49 |
| 8/28/2019 | 147 | 56 |
| 9/4/2019 | 154 | 63 |
| 9/25/2019 | 175 | 84 |
| 10/2/2019 | 182 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

I'm not familiar with Teradata, but [`MOD`](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2019/Arithmetic-Trigonometric-Hyperbolic-Operators/Functions/MOD) seems available, so:

```
MOD(r.Dt - Min(r.Dt) Over (ORDER BY Dt), 91) AS current_output
```